# xdebug + phpstorm +typo3 extension

Tags: xdebug, typo3, phpstorm

I'm trying to get debugging running on my remote ubuntu server to debug typo3 extensions.

I've installed XDebug 2.2.0 and PHP-Storm 4.0 on my machine. It seems everything is working. If I set a breakpoint on any of the core classes it is hit.
As soon as I set a breakpoint in my extension - it is ignored. The closest I ever get on the page where my extension is some break at this place:
class.t3lib_svbase.php : Line 668

I tried all tutorials I found, but non helped my to get it working...

Any ideas?

ANSWER:
Thanks alot for the hints! It was a combination of two configuration errors:
1) It was in deed a symlink problem. I tried to map to the symlinked folder...
2) To be able to debug the stuff the xdebug.ini has to have the following lines otherwise nothing happens!!

```
xdebug.auto_trace=1
xdebug.collect_includes=1
xdebug.collect_params=1
xdebug.collect_return=1
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.extended_info=1
```

For some funny reason

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

has to be set too in the ini. If not and it is set with GET-Var or ini_set() it is not breaking at the extension...

Comment: Have you set up path mappings within PHPStorm?

Comment: Yes. But I didn't download the entire webroot, just the typo3conf/ext/ directory. But I mapped it to the correct absolute path on server.

Comment: Is there some way I can have a more detailed log out of xdebug on the server? Guess this might also help in finding the issue...

Comment: Yeah, you can enable the xdebug logging, but it tends to be a huge volume of unreadable data. You may have success getting the whole webroot and setting path mappings up for it. Problems I've had in the past like this have generally been because of paths/symlinks/apache redirects.

Comment: Breakpoints need to be set at the `real` file location.

Comment: Make sure to add the setting break at first line to catch those symlink issues.

Comment: Please add your findings as an answer. It is totally fine to answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a combination of two configuration errors:

- It was in deed a symlink problem. I tried to map to the symlinked
  folder...
- To be able to debug the stuff the xdebug.ini has to
  have the following lines

otherwise nothing happens!!

```
xdebug.auto_trace=1
xdebug.collect_includes=1
xdebug.collect_params=1
xdebug.collect_return=1
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.extended_info=1
```

For some funny reason

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

has to be set too in the ini. If not and it is set with GET-Var or ini_set() it is not breaking at the extension...